# Sitecore - application shortcut from content editor ribbon

Tags: sitecore

I am able to create an asp.net webform (aspx) application in Sitecore and place a shortcut in the start menu. That works fine. How can I launch that application from a ribbon button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've defined your application in the *Core* database (see the example at **/sitecore/content/Applications/Sitecore App Center**), you just need to implement a custom command and create a ribbon button. Command code is really simple (one line of code):

```csharp
  public class YourCustomCommand : Command
  {   
     public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
     {
        Windows.RunApplication("Name of your application item");
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can brief steps are :-

- Add new button in core DB.
- Create a new class overriding the Execute method.
- Create a new command to hook up the button up to the new class.

You can use the below code to launch your page in a new window.

```cs
SheerResponse.Eval("window.open('" + [PATH_TO_LAYOUT] + "','_blank')");
```

Check out [this](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/open-sitecore-content-editor-from-the-page-editor/) blog for full instructions.